# return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type

Tags: c

I am sorry if this has been asked previously but i have tried all the solutions available but still getting this error. someone please explain the meaning of this error and also the solution to avoid this.

```
char *find_char( char const *source,char const *chars ){
    char const *result=NULL;

    for(int i=0;*(chars+i);i++){
        for(int j=0;*(source+j);j++){
            if(*(chars+i)==*(source+j)){
                result=chars+i;
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

when compiling, the following error occurs:

```
6_1.c: In function ‘find_char’:
6_1.c:8:12: warning: return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
     return result;
            ^
6_1.c:12:9: warning: return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
  return result;
```

can constants cannot be returned?

Comment: Because the function should be declared to return `const` as well.

Comment: `char const *result` then `return result;` and your function type is `char *`? Seems pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: No need to answer in comments, especially now that we have good answers

Answer (score 4):

Your title is a bit misleading, and probably you misinterpreted the warning, too:

> warning: return discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
>   [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers] return result;

The function is declared as non-const, i.e. `char *find_char(...`, while `result` is declared as `const`, i.e. char `const *result`; Hence, statement `return result` would mean to return a pointer that is declared as `const` as being `non-const`, and thus the warning.

I'd suggest to define your function as `const char *find_char(...`.

Comment: @David C. Rankin: already corrected; slow internet here in the train :-)

Comment: Changing the function is likely not the desired fix. This relates to a well-known shortcoming in the C language: A caller to this function might want to search for a substring in their non-const string, and they want a non-const pointer as a result. The function declares its parameters as `const char *` because **it** does not change them, but it needs to return a `char *` to the caller. The solution is to use an explicit cast in the `return` statements, which the compiler will likely not warn about. This mirrors the declarations of the standard C library routines such as `strstr`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `result` is of type `char const *`, use const in the function signature to match it:

```
char const *find_char( char const *source,char const *chars )
```

Comment: Changing the function is likely not the desired fix. This relates to a well-known shortcoming in the C language: A caller to this function might want to search for a substring in their non-const string, and they want a non-const pointer as a result. The function declares its parameters as `const char *` because **it** does not change them, but it needs to return a `char *` to the caller. The solution is to use an explicit cast in the `return` statements, which the compiler will likely not warn about. This mirrors the declarations of the standard C library routines such as `strstr`.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the function `find_char` does not match the type of `result`. They are `char *` and `char const *` respectively.

Change the return type of the function `find_char` to `char const *`.

Comment: Changing the function is likely not the desired fix. This relates to a well-known shortcoming in the C language: A caller to this function might want to search for a substring in their non-const string, and they want a non-const pointer as a result. The function declares its parameters as `const char *` because **it** does not change them, but it needs to return a `char *` to the caller. The solution is to use an explicit cast in the `return` statements, which the compiler will likely not warn about. This mirrors the declarations of the standard C library routines such as `strstr`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Agree. Initially I wanted to add a note to the post stating that the change should depend on what the caller wants to do with the return value. But waited to see if the OP would clarify this in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

This relates to a well-known shortcoming in the C language, which I will discuss below. Presuming we want `find_char` to return a `char *` even though its inputs are `const char *`, you should use an explicit cast in the `return` statement:

```
return (char *) result;
```

With `return result;`, there is an implicit conversion from `char *` to the incompatible type `const char *`. The compiler warns because this could be a mistake. With the explicit cast, you show the compiler the conversion is intentional, and it is not likely to warn. (If it does, you can turn off that particular warning category.)

Regarding the shortcoming in C, consider the nature of `find_char`. It is similar to the C library routine `strstr`, which suffers from the same issue:

- The caller may have a `char *` and want a `char *` as a result.
- We would like the function parameters to be `const char *` to inform the compiler that the function does not alter the strings it is passed, because this may create some optimization opportunities.
- The function returns a pointer into one of its input strings. So it internally has a `const char *` but must return a `char *`, so it must convert it.

In other words, we have a `char *`, and we want to tell the compiler “Ths function will accept a `char *`, and it will not change the content, but it will return a `char *` result.” To do this in C, it is necessary to declare the parameter to be `const char *` but to convert the result pointer to `char *` before returning it.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2068.pdf